# Visual studio freezes while receiving data from Arduino through serial port

Tags: port

Visual studio receives unknown serial port data from Arduino. I send the data with a "9594" at the start of data in order to get right data. What could I do for freezing when I debug?

I use Visual Studio 2010 Express. I could see the data in the textbox continuously, but while I start receiving the debugged form freezes which I cannot do any other operation (like clicking a button etc.) I tried changing reading data time, serial timeout etc. But the program still freezes.

```
private void button19_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                string x = serialPort1.ReadLine();


                if (x.IndexOf("9594") >= 0)
                {

                    x = x.Remove(0, 4);           
                    double y = double.Parse(x); 
                    string z = textBox10.Text;
                    double zd = double.Parse(z);
                    textBox12.Text = x;
                    if (y < zd)
                    {

                        power_limit_turn_off_plugs();

                    }
                    else if (y > zd)
                    {
                        turn_to_last_state_of_plugs();
                    }
                }
            }

            catch (TimeoutException)
            { }
        }
}
```

Serial output is like(Arduino side):

```
95940.00
95940.00
95945.51
95945.51
95948.93
95948.93
95945.51
```

Comment: Use meaningful variable names, things like x,y,z makes code unreadable. I am struggling to find out what is going on there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is expected since you are blocking the UI thread with an endless `while` loop. You should perform your long running tasks in a different thread.

Keep it mind that once you try to reach form controls from another thread you will encounter with `InvalidOperationException`.

This post explains a lot.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-make-thread-safe-calls-to-windows-forms-controls

Just set `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false` at the beginning then when you learn some more do the right fix that explained in the link above.